# I have hit a weight loss plateau. Could my lower water intake have something to do with this?

Tags: plateau

I have hit a weight loss plateau.
I have noticed that I have started drinking far less water than when I started my workout plan, and even a bit more sugar. So could it be that because of my lower water intake I have hit this weight loss plateau?
Thank you for your help.:)

Comment: Water has no calories. Sugar does. However, it's more likely that you just need to change your routine around some.

Answer (score -1):

1.Well first of we must realize that our body does not want us to lose weight. Fat accumulation is the body's Survival mechanism. Back in stone age, accumulation of Fat was vital for survival(Who knew when was the next meal!). So now all you have to do to lose that fat is to CHEAT the body!
Yes, Cheat. Which means that once you follow some routine for some time, the body gets adjusted to it and tries to minimize fat loss. You have to keep changing your Workouts at least every two months to continue getting results. If you:
gym: change the type of exercises for the same muscle groups
Cycle/Running/Cardio: Mix Fast and endurance

2.Another thing to Note is that if one has excess of fat, then workouts without strict diets will easily help in initial fat loss... but as you progress, you HAVE to maintain a good Diet.
Good Diet + great Workouts = Healthy Body!!
and do change the diet patterns every two months so as to not quit due to boredom!:)

3.Regarding the water intake, Water is a prime resource for recovery. After Workouts , while resting, The body recovers all the muscles and it needs the Water. Besides, Water has never harmed any one so Drink up! ;)
Enjoy Your training and do comment if you have any queries!